# Rspec rails testing - join table not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

(I replicated an isolated example of my issue on github: https://github.com/diingo/jobs_emps. It contains just the problematic portion - no views, no controllers, just the models I describe below and the breaking test.)

My code is working on development and production but currently a portion is breaking only in the test environment leaving me unable to test it properly.

Here's what's happening:

I have two models, jobs and employees. Each job has employees that oversee and participate in it as a specific role (employee_type) - Manager or Exective. Employees can be promoted - a manager can be promoted to an executive. But their roles for previous jobs they participated in must remain the same.

A join between employees and jobs (JobsEmployee) keeps track of the employee's role through the `employee_type` attribute. The join will not update a user's position if it was previously set - this is done with a `before_save`, as seen here:

```
    class JobsEmployee < ActiveRecord::Base
      before_save :set_user_type

      def set_user_type
        self.user_type ||= self.user.type
      end
    end
```

This works fine in actual use on development and production. If a job is created, with a manager and exective, `job.jobs_employees` will show one manager and one executive. If a manager is promoted to executive and that job is then updated for whatever reason, `job.jobs_employees` will still show one manager and one executive.

However, during testing this changes. Upon updating a job, if an employee was promoted, `job.jobs_employees` shows two executives.

My test is shown below. You can see I abstracted controller create and update methods into models for convenience. You can reference them on the github link: https://github.com/diingo/jobs_emps/blob/master/app/models/job.rb

```
    RSpec.describe JobsEmployee, :type => :model do
      before do
        @job_permitted_params = {
          city: "Munich",
          status: "in_progress"
        }
        @manager = Employee.create!(name: "Bob Bobber", type: 'Manager')
        @executive = Employee.create!(name: "Alice Smith", type: 'Executive')
        @job_raw_params = {
          job: {
            manager_id: @manager.id,
            executive_id: @executive.id
          }
        }
      end

      it "creates and updates" do
        job = Job.create_with_params(@job_permitted_params, @job_raw_params)
        # This passes:
        expect(job.jobs_employees.map &:employee_type).to include("Manager", "Executive")
        @manager.type = 'Executive'
        @manager.save!

        Job.update_with_params(job, @job_permitted_params, @job_raw_params)
        # This breaks in testing but works in production:
        expect(job.jobs_employees.map &:employee_type).to include("Manager", "Executive")
      end
    end
```

I put break points (pry debugger) in `JobsEmployee#set_user_type` to see what might be happening. It appears like the record in JobsEmployee are deleted before or during a Job update. So instead of seeing that `self.user_type` is already set in `self.user_type ||= self.user.type`, it just runs `self.user.type` again.

Here is the schema. You can also see it in the github link.

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150301232938) do

      create_table "employees", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "type"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      create_table "jobs", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "city"
        t.string   "status"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

      create_table "jobs_employees", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "employee_type"
        t.integer  "employee_id"
        t.integer  "job_id"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
      end

    end
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Thanks so much for checking out the problem.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on without your schema.  I can't see anything in your test that will cause a JobsEmployee ever to be created.

Comment: @Gene I just added the schema. You can see all the code in the github link too if that helps to add context.

Comment: This line: `self.employee_ids = [manager_id, executive_id]` is not like any rails code I've seen before. What documentation makes you think this works? You're counting on this line to create AND update two jobs_employees records joining the job and employees? Why would that work? A wild guess is that it's creating both times. There is no uniqueness constraint on the join table to prevent it. This means you're getting the right answer in dev and prod by luck. With multiple join records per joined pair, the one you get when querying is random.

Answer (score 0):

The "actual use" you are describing may not correlate with your test. Updating a job and changing an employee's role would not necessarily cause the wholesale reassignment of `jobs_employees` association that you are doing in your test. I suspect that when you are doing that, Rails is comparing the set of JobsEmployee records represented by the ids you are assigning to the currently associated records. Since the currently associated records have the `user_type` field set, they aren't equivalent to the records that would be created upon a fresh assignment, so they are deleted and new ones regenerated.